# I can't help coding

Tags: grammar

I was reading a book of english grammar and here I am having a problem.

*The word 'can't' is contraction for 'cannot.' Combined with 'help' you are communicating something you are unable to control or having a hard time gaining a grasp for.*

there were examples as follows :
*"I can't help thinking about it."*
*"I can't help shopping so much."*

But where I am having problem is this :
`I can't help coding`
Where I wanted to say "I can't stop myself from coding".
It is seeming like it is not correct. May be I am wrong.

Comment: You've got it right.  *I can't help coding* means you cannot stop yourself from coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is also a good answer to your question. You perfectly know the meaning and use of "can't help". We can also use "but" after help with a bare-infinitive, which conveys the same meaning such as I can't help but think about it, I can't help but code, etc.